# Consume a body that is not quite JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am developing web application based on Jersey REST API. I am developing a  POST service based on client requirement (input parameters in JSON format) and its working fine. Now they want to change the input format as below. Now i am getting 415 error (unsupported media type).

This is old JSON format and its works well:

```
 {
    "weight": 5.0,
    "length": 1.5,
    "width": 2.7,
    "height": 0.7
}
```

and this the format client need to send.

```
{
weight = 12;
with = 78;
height = 78;
length = 5;
}
```

and this is my POST service:

```
@POST
@Path("/insert")
@Consumes({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

previously iam using

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not JSON anymore. Have a look at http://www.json.org/ and you'll see that a parameter name string must be enclosed in double quotation marks. So you'll have to decide to either listen to the client and create your own [`MessageBodyReader`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.9/jersey/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) to handle this custom format, or to tell the client that they need to send valid JSON.